# How do I get a UITableView to autoresize?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autoresize, autosize

I have a couple of side-by-side UITableViews in a UIView, and I would like to get the whole thing to autoresize.  I have a UIView In my init() method am doing:

```
// I don't know how big frontBack should be, so I'd like it to autosize
UIView *frontBack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
frontBack.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, r.size.width / 2, height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
table.dataSource = model1;
[table reloadData];
[frontBack addSubview:table];

... (add second table similarly, except with model2)
...
controller.view = frontBack;
```

This does not work.  The tables are 'height' pixels tall (which is smaller than what they need;  the text is cut off).

I've tried several ways of getting the UITableViews to resize, with no luck

```
// contentSize is correct, but frame size does not change
[table reloadData];
table.frame.size.height = table.contentSize.height;

// contentSize is correct, but bounds does not change
[table reloadData];
table.bounds.size.height = table.contentSize.height;

// Nothing appears to change
[table setNeedsLayout];
[table layoutIfNeeded];

// Again, no change
[table sizeToFit];
```

I assume I am missing something basic here, but I'd be grateful if someone could point out what it is.

Comment: What are you trying to display in your `UITableViews`? TableViews are scrollviews and usually scroll their content if needed?

Comment: Also if `height` pixels is too small, why do you set it to that?

Comment: When do you want to resize?

Comment: Also call `[table reloadData]` after you configure your `table`

Comment: @Tobi:  'height' pixels is too small, but I'd prefer not to have to compute the actual size:  I'd have to find out how big the table's margins are, how tall the header is, etc.  All that is what the autosizing is for!

Comment: @ipinak:  it can resize any time before it's drawn.  Since it isn't resizing, I'm trying to do it immediately because then I can try to figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

> table.bounds.size.height = table.contentSize.height;

This is a read-only property, you need to set the frame again.

Also, Are you sure your containing UIView isn't cutting off the table content?  You should resize it as well.

Comment: I've tried resizing it, too, with the methods given above, but since the UITableViews aren't resizing properly, I guess I can't expect the UIView to work properly.

Comment: There's no way of just knowing the table height, you would have to compute it.  If you're using 6.0+, then why not use Constraints?